# Can you convert MEAN applications with a compiler to App store?

Tags: node.js, cordova, mean-stack

As we all know you can use compilers as Cordova to convert web applications so you can upload your application to the app store.

This can easily be done when developing with HTML5 and Node.
But is it possible to convert a MEAN application (MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node)?

Comment: make hosted Cordova app: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can run nodejs server on mobile with [jxcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore), but I think you should run only client side part on cordova and api shall stay on server. Ideally, I think that api and client side must be separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.
*MEAN* stack is full stack. You can make your frontend an app with *cordova* but you still need database and backend service.
But that's ok. Make your app mobile friendly and stick with your server to provide the data you need to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, it's to create hosted web app. This is existing web application, just wrapped to make it possible to submit to app store.

For this you can use [Manfoldjs](http://manifoldjs.com/), for example [Using Cordova Plugins in Hosted Web Apps](https://github.com/pwa-builder/ManifoldJS/wiki/Using-Cordova-Plugins-in-Hosted-Web-Apps) or if you use Visual Studio, you can use [Visual Studio Tools 
for Apache Cordova](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/).